# driver.page_source is not defined

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a client-side-rendered web page using Selenium.

I started by creating a virtual environment and installing the required dependencies. Then I downloaded the Chrome Driver for my Chrome version and pasted it in the project's folder.

```py
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = os.path.abspath('') + '/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path)

print(' > Getting web page...')

url = 'https://www.someurl.com'

driver.get(url)

print(' > Sleeping...')

time.sleep(10)

print(' > Done. Html below:')

page_html = driver.page_source
print(page_source)
```

The browser open and the page loads. But after the program wakes up I get `NameError: name 'page_source' is not defined`. Any clues about what I might be doing wrong?

One thing that got me concerned is that I'm using 64-bit Windows, but the only driver available on Chrome's webpage was 32-bit. Anyways, it seems that this isn't a problem since the browser and the page are rendered correctly by the script.

Comment: 32-bit for windows is actually the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo from print.

```
print(page_html)
```

Instead of

```
print(page_source)
```

page_source is never initialized in your code.